# Default drawable folder in android

Tags: android, image, drawable

Ok so I have 4 folders in my res directory: drawable-mdpi,drawable-hdpi,drawable-xhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi. I wanted to know how to make a DEFAULT drawable folder where I could place images and if there was no image found in the specific density folders, the android device would look in the defualt one. So I created one with no qualifiers named drawable. The problem is when I put an image in my new created folder, it appeared differently than when I placed it in a specific density drawable folder.. Even though I was using the exact same image. How did changing folders affect my image..?

Answer (score 2):

The default `drawable` folder will be interpreted as `mdpi`, essentially. So any image you put in there will be rendered 1:1 on an mdpi device, scaled to 1.5x on hdpi, and scaled to 2x on xhdpi, etc.

Comment: What if I want a folder that I directly reference and the image I reference in code has those exact dimensions regardless of density?

Comment: @user3843164 for that you want the drawable--nodpi directory.

Answer (score 0):

All those folders are related to the phone you are using, you can open a default drawable folder named "drawable" but if you want to know, the drawable-mdpi for example is for samsung galaxy tab 10" (and more), you can read more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html